# Symfony routing - locale as subdomain with fallback to default

Tags: php, routes, annotations, locale, symfony

I'm trying to set up routing system with subdomain representing current locale. Routing is set via `@Routing` annotation and looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage",
 *      host="{locale}.{domain}",
 *      defaults={"locale" = "en", "domain" = "%domain%"},
 *      requirements={"locale" = "en|de|fr", "domain" = "%domain%"}
 * )
 */
```

Works well for URL's like `en.somedomain.com` or `de.somedomain.com`, but fails to find correct route for `somedomain.com`, without locale.

I understand that because of the `host` parameter, that is set to represent exact **locale.domain** pattern, but I can't find way to tell Symfony routing system that there could be additional, default `host`.

Searched all around for this, but found nothing particular. Would appreciate any help!

**UPDATE**

There is actually a way to do it, by adding another `@Route` in annotation, without `host` parameter:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage_default",
 *      defaults={"locale" = "en"}
 * )
 */
```

but thats looks a bit dirty, and I'm not using `%domain%` parameter there, which is important for me - say, if I would need another subdomain for mobile version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, looks like triple annotation routing to handle locale + subdomain is the only choice for now.

Studying documentation (for example, [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)) shows that Symfony developers encourage us to do it that way, which, to me, is not that nice. However, here's the solution...

```
/**
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage",
 *      host="{mobile}.{_locale}.{domain}",
 *      defaults={"mobile" = "moblie", "locale" = "%locale%", "domain" = "%domain%"},
 *      requirements={"mobile" = "mobile|m", "_locale" = "%locale%|de|fr",  "domain" = "%domain%"}
 * )
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage",
 *      host="{_locale}.{domain}",
 *      defaults={"_locale" = "%locale%", "domain" = "%domain%"},
 *      requirements={"_locale" = "%locale%|de|fr", "domain" = "%domain%"}
 * )
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage_default",
 *      defaults={"_locale" = "%locale%"}
 * )
 */
```

Notice that order is important, starting from subdomains, going down to default. As this looks ugly with `@Route` annotation, I've decided to re-write this in `YAML` as well:

```
homepage_locale_mobile:
    path:      /
    host:      "{mobile}.{_locale}.{domain}"
    defaults:  { mobile: "mobile", _locale: "%locale%", domain: "%domain%" }
    requirements:
        mobile:  "mobile|m"
        _locale: "%locale%|de|fr",
        domain:  "%domain%"

homepage_locale:
    path:      /
    host:      "{_locale}.{domain}"
    defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%", domain: "%domain%" }
    requirements:
        _locale: "%locale%|de|fr",
        domain:  "%domain%"

homepage:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _locale: "%locale%" }
```

Ordered as well. Maybe someone will come across and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem with defaults, though it was a route parameter and not locale.

The solution was there to replace the = signs with : as it should be that and the compiler somehow doesn't complains about it.

So try this one out:

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *      "/",
 *      name="homepage",
 *      host="{locale}.{domain}",
 *      defaults={"locale" : "en", "domain" : "%domain%"},
 *      requirements={"locale" : "en|de|fr", "domain" : "%domain%"}
 * )
 */
```

Comment: That is quite useful to know, however, my problem is not with compiler errors; it's Symfony 'Unable to find correct route' exception when I request the default domain. And the problem is that I can't define multiple `host` parameters, like: `host={"{locale}.{domain}", "{domain}"}`. Annotations above all fine and working.

Comment: I thought the cause of the problem is that Symfony "cannot see" that default locale setting and that is why it cannot match a route to it; because I didn't get any compiler errors previously but my default parameter just didn't work.